# sublime text2 text replace pattern in all files except one or more files

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext

I want to find and replace a particular word in all my project files except one or more files in sublime text. I am not sure how to specify that.

SO basically I want to exclude

```
/Uses/project_name/css/my_file.css
```

/Uses/project_name/css/my_file2.css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Menu: `Find-> Find in Files...`

Sublime is gonna open a new panel at the bottom, you just need to fill the fields.

```
Find: the_word_you_are_looking_for
Where: your_project_directory
Replace: the_word_that_is_going_to_replace_the_old_one
```

Then click on the button `...` located on the right side of the field `Where:`, and after click in the option `Add Exclude Filter`; replace the `-*.txt` with `my_file?.css` or `my_file*.css`